# Trying to do the holy grail in HTML, trying to make a ul in the side bar but the list is going over to the main content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do the holy grail but when I put the ul in my aside code the bullet points are in the main content, I tried padding, margin but I can't get the bullet points out of the main and in the aside area of my code.  Would I need to use JS to fix this issue, problem is I am still new to development and I am not too good with JS.

CODE:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 3;
}

header {
  background: orangered;
}

main {
  background: yellowgreen;
}

footer {
  background: deeppink;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.aside {
  background: forestgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  header,
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
main {
  flex: 2;
  order: 2;
  min-height: 80vh;
}
.nav-bar {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.aside {
  flex: 1;
  order: 3;
}
footer {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <title></title>
   <meta name="description" content="">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="holygrail.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <header>
         <h1><i>Lorem ipsum dolor</i></h1>
      </header>
      <main>
         <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit 
            perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde 
            repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit 
            perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde 
            repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit 
            perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde 
            repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit 
            perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde 
            repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!
         </h6>
         </h6>
      </main>
      <nav class="nav-bar">
         <h3>Favorite Teams</h3>
         <a href="https://www.nba.com"target="_blank">Favorite Team</a><br>
         <a href="https://www.nba.com"target="_blank">Favorite Team</a>
      </nav>
      <aside class="aside">
         <h3><strong><i>My Bucket List</i></strong></h3>
         <br>
         <h3>Things I want to Accomplish? </h3>
         <ul>
            <li>Hawaii</li>
            <li>Bahamas</li>
            <li>Mauritius</li>
            <li><del>New York City</del></li>
            <li><del>Statue of Liberty</del></li>
            <li>All the states in the USA</li>
         </ul>
      </aside>
      <footer>&copy; Copyright 2020</footer>
   </div>
   <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Manendar Verma Not related to your question but you are closing the h6 twice, which makes the HTML invalid and it may misbehave.

Comment: oh yeah I guess I am, didn't even notice.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your css:

```css
aside li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: is using -(negative) px a good practice or is there a better way than using -(negative) px?

Comment: It is a common practice, I guess it depends on the situation; in this case, it was not necessary but there are cases where it is simpler to just use negative values

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the width of the `li` elements are pushing the bullets out of the container. I've added the following code in the snippet below:

```css
.aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.aside ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

The key part is the `width: fit-content`, which is supported in modern browsers, but probably not ones like IE or Edge or old versions of Safari. This property value makes the `ul` be as wide as the content of the longest `li`, but no wider, allowing the bullets to remain within the `aside`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 3;
}

header {
  background: orangered;
}

main {
  background: yellowgreen;
}

footer {
  background: deeppink;
}

.nav-bar {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.aside {
  background: forestgreen;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  header,
  footer {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

main {
  flex: 2;
  order: 2;
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.nav-bar {
  order: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.aside {
  flex: 1;
  order: 3;
}

.aside {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.aside ul {
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

footer {
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="holygrail.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1><i>Lorem ipsum dolor</i></h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi! Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Tempore asperiores aliquam fugiat corrupti quis suscipit perferendis quod beatae doloribus minus iure incidunt, unde repellendus odit illo voluptas dignissimos, ea modi!
      </h6>
      </h6>
    </main>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
      <h3>Favorite Teams</h3>
      <a href="https://www.nba.com" target="_blank">Favorite Team</a><br>
      <a href="https://www.nba.com" target="_blank">Favorite Team</a>
    </nav>
    <aside class="aside">
      <h3><strong><i>My Bucket List</i></strong></h3>
      <br>
      <h3>Things I want to Accomplish? </h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Hawaii</li>
        <li>Bahamas</li>
        <li>Mauritius</li>
        <li><del>New York City</del></li>
        <li><del>Statue of Liberty</del></li>
        <li>All the states in the USA</li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
    <footer>&copy; Copyright 2020</footer>
  </div>
  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```